# If all html elements inside a whatever element are hidden, then hide a specific html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue where what I want is to check if all the `tr` elements with `class="RateContainer"` inside that div are hidden(`display:none` because of `hide()`). And if they are hidden pls select for example `class="elementToHide"` and hide it also:

```html
<div class="elementToHide">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="cabeceraTarifas">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#HotelAccordion0" href="#collapse2" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false"></a>
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body no-padding">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="RateContainer" style="display:none">

                        </tr>
                        <tr class="RateContainer" style="display:none">

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have tried is this:

```js
$(".panel-body.no-padding>table>tbody>tr").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).find(">table>tbody>tr:visible").length == 0) {
                        $('.elementToHide').hide();
                    }
                });
```

Also this:

```js
$(".panel-body.no-padding").filter(function () {
     return $(this).find("tr:visible").length == 0;
  }).hide();
```

And this:

```js
var elementsHidden = $(".panel-body.no-padding").not(function () {
      return ($(this).children(":visible").length > 0) ? false : true;
    });
$(".resultElementos").html(elementsHidden.length);
//And here them if length == 0 them take the bif father and hide him from the cops jeje
```

But I´m not able to hide it!!, do you know why??
Thank you (:

Comment: You have `tr`s that not hidden (all the `tr`s that doesn't have `hidden` class I guess)

Comment: @Pete I don't see why not. I tried Flex and all, but tables are the most robust and reliable method to define a regular layout. They never break and never fail. I don't know why people say "You shouldn't use tables" because I do and I love them.

Comment: @MoshFeu Hi,yes all the `tr`s with class "RateContainer" are hidden

Comment: Thank you @Pete , What do you suggest?, also the question it wasnt at all about tables, or because of its use I´m not able to do what I need????

Comment: @Pete yes pete I dont really care about how it will be the selector, I mean, the only thing I want is this: "If all `tr`s inside this `tbody` has the css property `display:hidden`(not all tbody) then... hide (whateverSelector)"

Comment: Working for me: https://jsbin.com/veviqam/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @MoshFeu I dont know whi i cannot do it....problaby something out of this, so let me check and I´ll let you know